# Database Exception when binding datagrid

Tags: c#, mysql

```
public void FillGrid()
{
    string connString = "Server =localhost;Port = 3306; Database =lbmtcs; UID =serverUser; Password =";
    MySqlConnection Pathway = new MySqlConnection(connString);

    string gridView = "SELECT PIN, Status, Cert_Title_No, Owner_Name, Co_Owner, Street, Barangay FROM landrecord"
                        +"WHERE PIN = @pin, Status = @Stat AND Cert_Title_No = @Cert AND Owner_Name = @Owner AND Co_Owner = @CO AND Street = @St AND Barangay = @Bar";
    MySqlCommand grid = new MySqlCommand(gridView, Pathway);
    MySqlDataAdapter MyDA = new MySqlDataAdapter();
    MySqlCommandBuilder cmd = new MySqlCommandBuilder(MyDA);
    MyDA.SelectCommand = grid;

    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    MyDA.Fill(table);

    BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();
    bSource.DataSource = table;
    dGrid.DataSource = bSource;

}
```

MySqlException was unhandled:

> Fatal error encountered during command execution.

Whats wrong in the code?

I'm selecting some columns to show in my datagrid.

Comment: for starters I would change the gridView variable to be something like strSQL 2nd where are you creating the Parameters..?
Pathway change that to sqlConn clean up your code a bit and use variables that make sense just FYI

Comment: Do you just want to display data or are you planning on saving and updating etc? Let me know as it changes the answer.

Comment: thanks dash.. followed what u posted.. this is new error..
cant seem to find the right type.. i used int in my database..

Incorrect format on DbType.. all Int creates this error

Comment: MySqlParameter parameter = new MySqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@pin", DbType = DbType.Int32, Value = Int32.Parse(txtPin.Text) };

whats wrong with this code? Error is Incorrect FOrmat

Answer (score 2):

Between @pin and Status should be an AND and not a ,

Comment: changed my code to what u all said.. still same error..
this is what im trying to do.
input from textbox ->data to mysql database then datagrid will show whats inside the database.